# Forward fill only certain value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, ffill

I have an array which represents object states, where 0 - object is off, and 1 - object is on.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = [np.nan, 0, np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 0, np.nan, 1, np.nan]
df = pd.DataFrame(s, columns=["s"])
df
      s
0   NaN
1   0.0
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   1.0
5   NaN
6   NaN
7   0.0
8   NaN
9   1.0
10  NaN
```

I need to forward will only 0-values in it, like below.

```
>>> df_wanted
      s
0   NaN
1   0.0
2   0.0
3   0.0
4   1.0
5   NaN
6   NaN
7   0.0
8   0.0
9   1.0
10  NaN
```

After browsing similar queations here, I just compare `ffill`-ed and `bfill`-ed values and assign back with a mask:

```
mask = (df.ffill() == 0) & (df.bfill() == 1)
df[mask] = 0
df
      s
0   NaN
1   0.0
2   0.0
3   0.0
4   1.0
5   NaN
6   NaN
7   0.0
8   0.0
9   1.0
10  NaN
```

But it won't help if any 0 value is not followed by 1. What could be more elegant solution that takes such cases into account?

Comment: Why not only use `mask = (df.ffill() == 0)`, am I missing anything?

Comment: Does this suffice : ``df.ffill().where(lambda df: df.eq(0), df)`` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mask = (df.ffill() == 0)` should only be suffice to fulfill your usecase.

Firstly, `df.ffill` will propagate the last valid observation forward. So rows followed by `0` will be filled by `0s`, and rows followed by `1` will be filled by `1s`. Compare that to `0` to select rows with `0s` only and use it as mask to get your final df.

**Example**:  *(Added a **0** and few **NaNs** to the end of your df)*

```
>>> s = [np.nan, 0, np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 0, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan, 0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(s, columns=["s"])
>>> df
      s
0   NaN
1   0.0
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   1.0
5   NaN
6   NaN
7   0.0
8   NaN
9   1.0
10  NaN
11  NaN
12  0.0
13  NaN
14  NaN
15  NaN
>>> 
>>> 
>>> df[df.ffill() == 0] = 0
>>> df
      s
0   NaN
1   0.0
2   0.0
3   0.0
4   1.0
5   NaN
6   NaN
7   0.0
8   0.0
9   1.0
10  NaN
11  NaN
12  0.0
13  0.0
14  0.0
15  0.0
```

Comment: Thanks, now I see where I over-engineered my solution.

Answer (score 3):

One way, maybe not much elegant but that works for you, would be to just ffill with everything and then pick from it where your original series was NaN and your ffilled series is 0.

```
sf = df.ffill().values[:, 0]
desired = np.where(np.isnan(s) & (sf==0), sf, s)
```

pandas has a `where` function too, I'm just more comfortable with numpy since it's more versatile.